# How do I disable file sorting on usb drives?

Tags: usb, filemanager, sort

Are there any file managers that allow unsorted folders on usb drives?  I can select manual sort on my hard drives fine, but when I connect a usb mass storage device the option for manual sort is gone and everything is sorted by name by default.

- I need to sort while in list or compact view. It turns out that the reason I can sort manually on my other drives is because they are in icon view. This doesn't help on my usb mp3 player because if I manually sort the files as icons they just default to whatever sorting is set for list view on the usb mass storage mp3 player. The only way I've found to get around this is to us windows xp to manually sort the files.
- I've now tried thunar, pcman file manager, dolphin, xfe, krusader, tux commander, and GNOME commander. I can't seem to sort manually in list or compact view in any of these. Maybe I'm missing the setting to disable automatic sorting?

Comment: I need to add that I need to sort while in list or compact view. It turns out that the reason I can sort manually on my other drives is because they are in icon view.  This doesn't help on my usb mp3 player because if I manually sort the files as icons they just default to whatever sorting is set for list view on the usb mass storage mp3 player.  The only way I've found to get around this is to us windows xp to manually sort the files

Comment: I've now tried thunar, pcman file manager, dolphin, xfe, krusader, tux commander, and GNOME commander.  I can't seem to sort manually in list or compact view in any of these. Maybe I'm missing the setting to disable automatic sorting?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!